# Can I use `bool` type or opaque pointers to classes in a c++ function exported to c?

Tags: c++, c

I am working on the API of a library I am writing. The library itself will be written in `c++`, but the API will be exported using `extern "C"` for best cross-language compatibility (I will be consuming this API later from `C#`, `C++`, maybe `C` and a few others).
Obviously, the API can't include whole classes or other `c++` specific features (like throwing exceptions), but my questions are:

1. Can I use the `bool` type in the exported API? After all, it is a POD.
2. Can I use opaque pointers to classes? If so, how would I declare them in the header file so that the header file can be used from `C` code?

Comment: `typedef struct foo * Foo` works in C and C++. And you can later define `foo` as a class in C++.

Comment: @AlanStokes: Are you sure you can forward declare a struct but define a class?  I think MSVC gave me errors when I did that.

Comment: @Dietrich Yes, it's completely legal. But it can trigger sanctimonious warnings.

Comment: @Alan: But what would be the point.  `class {` and `struct { private:` are interchangeable.

Comment: @Ben To the compiler, yes (modulo base class visibility). But use of `struct` only for PODs is not an uncommon convention.

Comment: @Alan: Using it to mark classes passed to the client is equally valuable, perhaps even moreso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally went ahead and tested it. Here are the test programs:

test_cpp.cpp:

```
#include "test.h"

class C {
    int a;
public:
    C() : a(42) {}
    int  getA() { return a; }
    void setA(int v) { a=v; }
};

int get7(bool b) { return b ? 7 : 3; }

C c;
C* getC() { return &c; }
int  getA(C* t) { return t->getA(); }
void setA(C* t, int v) { return t->setA(v); }
```

test_c.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "test.h"

int main()
{
    C* c = getC();
    printf("%d\n", getA(c));
    setA(c, 10);
    printf("%d\n", getA(c));
    printf("%d\n%d\n%d\n%d\n", get7(0), get7(1), get7(2), get7(-1));

    return 0;
}
```

test.h:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#else
#define bool _Bool
#endif

struct C;
typedef struct C C;

int get7(bool b);

C* getC();
int  getA(C* t);
void setA(C* t, int v);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Compiling with mingw64 gcc-4.9.0 on windows

```
gcc -c test_c.c
g++ test_cpp.cpp test_c.o
```

it compiled and ran correctly. Points of interest:

- `g++` had no problem at all with `C` being declared as a `struct` and later defined as a `class`
- c++ `bool` and `c` _Bool worked interchangeably

I tried this with MS compiler (VS2012) and it worked the same except for one small detail that I can't explain: In the header file, I had to change

```
int get7(bool b);
```

to

```
int get7(bool);
```

to get it to compile. If anyone can explain this I would be happy to understand it.

Answer (score 1):

Bool should be fine, the ABI and language designers are careful about these things (`complex<double>` from C++ and `complex double` from C are explicitly designed to be compatible, for example).  Classes can be turned into opaque pointers with forward declarations.

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
class MyClass;
#else
#include <stdbool.h>
typedef struct MyClass MyClass;
extern "C" {
#endif

bool IsActivated(MyClass *p, int x);

#ifndef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Note that I have seen ABI compatibility issues if various compiler flags or attributes are set—for example, `bool` is a different size in C and C++ using GCC 4.2 if structure packing is enabled.

Comment: So your conclusion is that booleans are portable for this, despite the evidence you listed that they aren't handled the same in C and C++?  Also, you're conflating ABI and language design.  No compiler or OS or architecture tags are present on this question, so if your answer is specific to gcc-linux-x86 then you need to say that.  (I promise that your answer, as it pertains to booleans, is completely wrong on Windows, where there is no C++ ABI standard at all)

Comment: @BenVoigt: It is merely a guess: based on the knowledge that other types that were added to the C and C++ standards (complex numbers) were explicitly designed for compatibility, my guess was that `bool`, which was also added to the C and C++ standards separately, would follow the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

1. **Can I use the bool type in the exported API? After all, it is a POD.** *bool is a C++ specific type and if you use it in your header file, that would not compile in C. Also standard does not specify how bool would be implemented, so it is better to rely on standard conversion from int to bool*
2. **Can I use opaque pointers to classes?** *I am not sure what you would wan't to achieve here. The generally accepted approach is to encapsulate the lifetime of your object within your C++ library and provide a set of C functions that would manipulate the object. Note, even if you somehow enable access to your class via the pointer, you would be stuck with name-mangling and calling convention*

Comment: `bool` is available in C and has been part of the official standard since 1999.

Comment: @DietrichEpp: 1. That does not guarantee that your code would compile with C89? 2. That does not guarantee that C and C++ would implement it in uniform manner. 3. All compilers are C99 compliant (My Solaris/IBM/AIX/MSVS ) does not recognizes bool as a datatype.

Comment: @DietrichEpp: Is that `bool` or `_Bool` ?

Comment: @BenVoigt: Actually the native type is _Bool while bool is defined in `stdbool.h`

Comment: @Abhijit: An opaque pointer means that the only thing that can be done with it is pass back to the library.  There are a couple ways of implementing object handles: opaque pointers are efficient but provide no protection against wild values being passed; indexes into a table of objects provide protection but with a runtime cost

Comment: @BenVoigt: Both.  `_Bool` is the keyword and `bool` is from `<stdbool.h>`.  Both have been standard since 1999.

Comment: @DietrichEpp: But there is nothing to make bool-the-C-typedef compatible with bool-the-C++-keyword.  I expect that most real implementations would do so, however.

Comment: The set of C functions to manipulate the object need a handle to the object. That is the opaque pointer

Comment: @BenVoigt: `_Bool` is a keyword in C and `bool` is a keyword in C++.  Are you talking about user-defined typedefs?

Comment: @DietrichEpp: No, you are the one talking about typedefs.  "`bool` is available in C".  In C, it is a typedef.

Comment: @BenVoigt: It is not a *user-defined* typedef.  It is always `typedef _Bool bool;`, so it is the same as `_Bool`.  Are you asking what makes `_Bool` in C the same as `bool` in C++?

Comment: @BenVoigt: It is not a sure thing, just a highly probable thing.  I would have serious problems with anyone who defined an ABI so that the boolean type for C and C++ had different representations, sizes, or alignment restrictions.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Although I should correct myself, there is no `typedef` for `bool` in C.  There is the keyword `_Bool` and the macro `bool` which expands to `_Bool`.

Comment: Ah, that was my bad assumption that it would use typedef.  It is a macro, to allow it to be undefined again.